# Python 3.6 is required. Current python version is ''

Tags: azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to use azure functions on Ubuntu and have the following error:

**Python 3.6 is required. Current python version is ''**

I've installed azure functions tools using:

**npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core --unsafe-perm true**

and trying to:

**func init <> --worker-runtime python**

Any idea why it fails?
Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

Depending what `sudo apt list --installed|grep python3.6` says you may want to install python3.6 via `sudo apt-get install python3.6`.

Comment: This is the output of the command: libpython3.6/bionic,now 3.6.5-3 amd64 [installed]
libpython3.6-dev/bionic,now 3.6.5-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libpython3.6-minimal/bionic,now 3.6.5-3 amd64 [installed]
libpython3.6-stdlib/bionic,now 3.6.5-3 amd64 [installed]
python3.6/bionic,now 3.6.5-3 amd64 [installed]
python3.6-dev/bionic,now 3.6.5-3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3.6-minimal/bionic,now 3.6.5-3 amd64 [installed]

Comment: I think the problem is related to nodejs trying to run python --version using some azure utilities. I'm following the steps from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/wiki/Create-Function-(CLI). python --version returns 3.6.5 so there shouldn't be a problem with python. Maybe I'm missing some permissions or something

Comment: I wonder what your `PYTHONPATH` says though. You may have a different version of Python set as default...

Comment: default python is 2.7. I'm using source <python3_venv>/bin/activate before calling func init, as advised in the link above